# Get data range by date from Thingspeak Channels api

Tags: api, logging, iot

I have logged tens of thousands of values in Thingspeak for a couple of months. When retrieving the data with the Channels api I can set the start parameter. If I set it to yesterday I will get everything after that (as long as the value count is below 8000, which is the maximum amount that can be retrieved in one request). If I set it to two months ago (after which about 20000 values have been logged) I will get the most recent 8000 values.

```
STARTTIMExxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXENDTIME
STARTTIMEXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxENDTIME
```

So now when I set start date (end date is implicitly set to now) I get the big X from the first row as in the example above when I want the values on the second row.

How would I get 8000 values from the moment I specify?

Is there any other way or do I actually need to set both start and end date and put an interval that is smaller than the time I can log 8000 values and then make more queries to the api to fill up my requested values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe both start and end date are required.  So, you'll need to page through your data set by date.  You'll have to guess how many dates you can get given the average data rate that you're logging at.